# proof of a lemma in Serre's book "A Course in Arithmetic" p 82

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Im trying to understuand the proof of this Lemma

> Let $\Omega$ be a lattice in $\Bbb C.$ The series :$$L:=\underset{0\neq\rho\in\Omega}{\sum}\frac{1}{|\rho|^t}$$
>   is absolutely convergent for $t>2.$

In the proof I find this statement ; "We note that the number of elements of $\Omega$ such that $|\rho|$ is between the consecutive integers $n$ and $n + 1$ is $O(n)$  so the convergence of $L$ is reduced to the convergence of $\sum_{r>0}\frac{1}{r^{t-1}}$
where $r$ is a positive integer, and we know that this converges for $t − 1 > 1$"

Can someone explain to me : why $\sharp\{\rho\in\Omega:n\leq|\rho|\leq n+1\}=O(n)$ ? and how I can use this to conclude that $L$ converge ?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for a moment that $\Omega$ is the integer lattice. Then the region described is an annulus centered at the origin, of inner radius $n$ and outer radius $n + 1$. The area of the outer disk is $\pi (n+1)^2$; the number of "cells" touching the outer disk is at most $\pi (n+2)^2$. Similarly, the number of cells completely within the inner disk is at least $\pi (n-2)^2$. So the number of cells meeting the annulus is no more that $\pi ( (n+2)^2 - (n-2)^2)$, which is $O(n)$.

(a "cell" is a unit square centered at a lattice point)

For your case, it's pretty much the same argument...but with a slightly different metric.

I hope this helps get you on your way, but if not, please try to explain where you got stuck.

Comment: A pleasure. That book is a lot of fun to read (at least the parts I got through), but I found that each page took me a couple of hours. :(

Comment: why do you assume that $\Omega$ is the integer lattice ?

Comment: I didn't assume it was the integer lattice -- I used the integer lattice as an example of how you might think about the problem. in general, the area of the annular region is such that only a linear number of cells (in $\Omega$) can intersect it. A rough proof might look like this: let $T $be a linear transform of the plane taking the integer latter to $\Omega$. Then distances are scaled  by at most a constant $c$. So the area between radii $r_1 $ and $r_2$ in the image is no more than the distance between, say $r_1 / c$ and $c r_2$, which is not too large.